# How do I define a static variable inherited from a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, static

I have a header with a struct in it:

```
#ifndef CHARACTER_H_
#define CHARACTER_H_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Character
{
    string name;
    static string type;
    static int baseHp, baseAttack, baseDefence;
};

#endif
```

I have a class inheriting that header and I would like to define the static variables in the struct in the inheriting class. Say my inheriting class is as follows:

```
#include "Character.h"
#include <string>

class Rouge: private Character
{
public:
    Rouge(string name)
    {
        this->name = name;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
};
```

Where in the `Rouge` class would I define the static variables declared in the `Character` header, and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Are you sure you understand the difference between declaration and definition, in its many contexts?

Comment: @KerrekSB Nope. Didn't think vocabulary mattered an extreme amount as long as people knew what I was talking about.. Hence the examples. (I'm not too good at terminology, anyway.)

Comment: @Steven: How are people supposed to know what you're talking about if you wilfully employ incorrect vocabulary? Of course it matters.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It wasn't willful.. I simply thought I knew what the words meant (or at least was confident enough) so I went ahead and used them. But I wasn't 100% sure of the definitions, so I admitted my mistake. Not trying to come off as rude or a jerk or whatever, but a common theme I find here is that others are unable to help people simply because they get caught up on terminology, despite the fact that the question is comprehensible enough. Don't get me wrong, I understand the importance of terminology and whatnot, it just frustrates me sometimes.

Comment: @StevenFontaine Electrical engineers don't say 'volts' when they mean 'ampereres', and if they did people would die, including other electrical engineers. There's no reason why IT should be any sloppier.

Comment: So, what exactly is the correct terminology so I can correct my question? (Assuming I should bother.. Is the terminology the reason the question is getting down voted or is there something else that I'm missing. I mean, you're not supposed to down vote a question because the person doesn't know what he's talking about.... Why else would he be asking a question...?)

Comment: @StevenFontaine: Don't see why you're complaining to me about people not helping when I answered your question. Terminology is _important_, and that is no less true just because experts can divine what you really meant to say through heuristics and intuition. Frankly, as the OP, you are not qualified to take shortcuts and assume that your approximations are unambiguous/unimportant. Not trying to come off as rude or a jerk or whatever.

Comment: I think the downvotes are a combination of "he hasn't read his C++ book and learnt the language", and burgeoning frustration across SO. I didn't downvote you as I don't think those things are valid reasons to downvote (or, at least, not sufficiently so in this particular case). But your downvotes are not out of character for SO considering the incorrect assumptions you've made in the premise of your question. HTH

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, sorry for complaining to you. I wasn't trying to complain, just trying to explain my stance, but it turned into complaining and I'm sorry about that. Also, thanks for the answer! :P I'm not usually this much of a typical, grumpy, internet person, but it's been a long day..

Comment: @StevenFontaine: The entire point of the question falls apart once you realise that static class data members are *declared* inside a class, but never *defined* inside a class. And since the members in question have already been declared, it's now completely unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @KerrekSB Alright. I (think I) understand what you're trying to say. I guess I just didn't understand quite how static variables worked in C++. (I primarily program in Java, but I'm learning C++ for school.. Trying to apply my Java knowledge is proving ineffective and making me look/feel stupid.. I suppose I should just stop making guesses as to the similarities between the languages.)

Comment: @StevenFontaine: Ah, yes, that would be the Captain Janeway approach to problem solving: Explain the difficult reality by an analogy with something familiar ("the event horizon is just like the frozen surface of a lake"), pretend the analogy is literal, act by solving the analogy ("we just need to break through the ice!"), profit. That doesn't always quite work for C++, unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define them as if `Rouge` did not exist; they are members of `Character`:

```
string Character::type;
int    Character::baseHp;
int    Character::baseAttack;
int    Character::baseDefence;
```

So, if you were expecting these to be different for each class deriving from `Character`, you will be disappointed: data members cannot be "overridden".

Instead, it is conventional to override getter functions that are declared in the base but made *pure virtual*, so that `Character` becomes pure and `Rouge` must override those functions such that the values for that particular type are returned on demand.

Comment: uhm, `name` is the only one that isn't static. but i agree the statics should be probably not be static. i think the OP is trying to do a meta-type thing, that some information should be shared between all instances of a type.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Oops

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's exactly what I'm trying to do. The type of Rouge is always going to be "Rouge", no matter the instance. Is this not the way to do this? (New to C++. I know Java fluently, but I'm in the middle of transitioning.)

Comment: Also they are inaccessible to `Rouge`, since the inheritance was private

Comment: @StevenFontaine: Pretty sure you mean Rogue, btw?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to implement fixed values that can be overriden per type is to use virtual functions that produce those values:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    virtual
    auto number_of_tails() const -> int { return 0; }
};

class Doggie
    : public Animal
{
public:
    auto number_of_tails() const -> int override { return 1; }
};
```

I hope I got that `override` keyword placed right.

If you want this information to be available without an instance of the class, simply implement it in terms of a static function:

```
class Doggie
    : public Animal
{
public:
    auto number_of_tails() const -> int override { return the_number_of_tails(); }

    static
    auto the_number_of_tails() const -> int { return 1; }
};
```

Disclaimer: code never touched by compiler.